# How to set default bluetooth profile for headset with pipewire

Tags: linux, arch-linux, bluetooth, pipewire

For some time now, my bluetooth headset automatically connects to *Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP, codec CVSD)*. I am looking for a way to make it automatically connect to *High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec aptX)* as it did before.
I found some solutions by looking in the web but it is for pulseaudio and I am using pipewire.
Any ideas ?
I am using updated version of Archlinux with pipewire.

EDIT : If I restart the pipewire services, the headset automatically connects with A2DP like I want but if I turn my headset off then on, it automatically connects with CVSD => That's what I don't want.

EDIT 2 : My headset is a Plantronics BackBeat Pro 2

EDIT 3 : I have an error when I turn on my headset, in journalctl! It is :

> src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed
> for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: Device or resource busy

EDIT 4 : Btw, I have no problem to switch to A2DP, if I open pavucontrol I can easily switch the profile there. The problem just comes from the profile selected when the headset connects to my computer.

Comment: I don't remember, but I do not have the problem anymore, maybe an update fixed it. Maybe you can try the answer of Atanas ?

Answer (score 2):

In [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1973004) they say `pactl` will still work for Pipewire.

To make switching profiles easier you can alias the commands there. Here's two I have attached to hotkeys:

```bsh
pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.<card ID> a2dp_sink
```

```
pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.<card ID> handsfree_head_unit
```

Comment: It works well but it is still manual. If I restart my headset, the selected profile will become HHU again. Using a hotkey to switch the profile seems to be an ugly solution compared to the fact that the headset was connecting automatically to A2DP profile some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, but opposite issue(wanted to be HSP/HFP by default).

After a long research this finally worked for me:

`sudo apt remove pipewire`

`sudo apt install wireplumber` a new PipeWire Session Manager.

Restart..

More info about `wireplumber` [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/WirePlumber).

Now 'Volume Control' keeps the previously selected profile.